# Error in Push Notifications while registering for iOS Twilio Voice Client

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, twilio, twilio-api

I am getting the following error while trying to register a user for the Twilio Voice client:

`[ERROR VoiceClient] Inside register:deviceToken:completion:, failed to register for Twilio push notifications. Error:Failed to register. Code: 6.`

Here is the setup:

- Push credentials have been registered with Twilio. A VoIP Push certificate has been registered and those kind of pushes are only in Production mode. Let's say the app ID is "com.bundle.appIDX".
- The server side has been setup so that the correct push credentials are fed to the `IpMessagingGrant` object.
- At the client side, the following piece of code is executed:
  `VoiceClient.sharedInstance().register(withAccessToken: self.accessToken, deviceToken: self.voipToken)`
- This immediately fails with the error above.
- Using version '=2.0.0-beta4' for TwilioVoiceClient, and using version '2.9.1' for twilio-node server side component (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/tree/2.9.1).
- Tried playing with "Use this credential for sending to a sandbox APN" option and no result.
- Tried using both development and provisioning profiles at the client side for the app ID "com.bundle.appIDX".

Is Twilio really supporting VoIP pushes? If yes, what could be wrong with this setup?

Thanks,
Guven.

**=======**
**Edit after Viktor's guidance:**
I now manually create the VoiceGrant. I set the value of the key property to `'voice'`. Here is what the grant looks like:

```
{ 
    outgoing_application_sid: 'APXX',
    push_credential_sid: 'CRXX',
    endpoint_id: 'XX' 
}
```

Still getting the registration error.

I have also tried this format since this is how it looks in 2.11.0 version:

```
{ outgoing:  { application_sid: 'APXX' },
  push_credential_sid: 'CRXX',
  endpoint_id: 'XX' 
}
```

Any ideas where the problem might be? Attaching the cloud code as well:

```
  var accessToken = new twilio.AccessToken("ACXX", "SKXX", "PPXX", accessTokenOptions);

  var voiceGrantConfig = {"outgoingApplicationSid": "APXX", 
                                "endpointId": clientName,
                                "pushCredentialSid": "CRXX"};

  var voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant(voiceGrantConfig);
  voiceGrant.key = "voice";
  console.log(voiceGrant.toPayload());
  accessToken.addGrant(voiceGrant);

  var token = accessToken.toJwt();
```

**Edit 2**: I have actually upgraded to twilio-node 2.11.0 and still getting the error. Here is the access token right before generating the jwt.

```
AccessToken {
  accountSid: 'ACXX',
  keySid: 'SKXX',
  secret: 'PPXX',
  ttl: 86400,
  identity: undefined,
  nbf: undefined,
  grants: 
   [ VoiceGrant {
       outgoingApplicationSid: 'APXX',
       outgoingApplicationParams: undefined,
       pushCredentialSid: 'CRXX',
       endpointId: 'XX' } ] }
```

Comment: Hi Guven, can you confirm that you are using Access Tokens: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens rather than Capability tokens: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens?

Comment: @MeganSpeir Hey Megan, yes I can confirm that. I am adding a IpMessagingGrant to the access token as well. That might be an issue though. The 2.9.1 twilio-node doesn't have the VoiceGrant, it only gets introduced in version 2.11.0.

Answer (score 3):

[Edited based on feedback from Guven]

You need a "voice" grant. Otherwise your requests will be denied to the Voice product. You either need to manually add that section to the JSON before signing it or you need to upgrade to the 2.11.0 version. Specifically your token needs to look like this:

```
{
  "sub": "ACxxxx",
  "iss": "SKxxxx",
  "grants": {
    "voice": {
      "outgoing": {
         "application_sid": "APxxxx"
      },
      "push_credential_sid": "CRxxxxx"
    },
    "identity": "voice_test"
  },
  "jti": "SKxxxxx",
  "exp": 1479315711
}
```

Note, also the "identity" element as well. This is the identifier of your user. Typically its username or an ID of the user record in your system.

Checkout the [quickstart app](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-python/blob/master/server.py) for a code sample for generating the right token (it's in Python but should give you a good idea of how to get started).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Viktor. I am really disappointed with Twilio support, it has been 2 days and no response so far. I don't think this was a complicated case. The documentation can really be improved.

Comment: Hey Viktor, there still seems to be an issue, I have updated my question. Can you please take a look?